# Search for null in id column over all tables programmatically

Tags: postgresql

I want to automatically check for null ID's over all id columns in my database, I have to check all tables of which there is about 50,000 so manually doing this is infeasible

Comment: nothing as of yet, i'm not that good with postgresql

Comment: Then have a look at [plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql.html) and [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/information-schema.html) views, namely tables and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function that isn't very elegant, nor optimized, but perhaps it can be a start to get you going. It loops over all tables in a database and in case a table contains a column with name *id* and if any row value in that column is NULL it will return the table name. The function is quite stupid as it will not check if the column is a primary key, just that its name is *id*. And I'm certain there is quite a big room for improvement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_tables_id()
  RETURNS table(tablename TEXT) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE row RECORD;
DECLARE has_id_col BIGINT;
DECLARE has_null BIGINT;

BEGIN       
    FOR row IN
    -- Restrict to specific database and schema if necessary by specifying 
    -- table_catalog='_dbname_' and/or table_schema='_schema_' in WHERE-clause
        SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
    LOOP
    -- Check if id col exists
    EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE column_name =''id'' 
        AND table_catalog=''' || quote_ident(row.table_catalog) || '''
        AND table_schema=''' || quote_ident(row.table_schema) || '''
        AND table_name=''' || quote_ident(row.table_name) || ''';' INTO has_id_col;
    IF has_id_col > 0 THEN
        -- Check if col ID is null
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) 
        FROM ' ||  quote_ident(row.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(row.table_name) || ' 
        WHERE id IS NULL' INTO has_null;
        -- Return table name
        IF has_null > 0 THEN
            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ''' ||  quote_ident(row.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(row.table_name) || '''::TEXT AS tablename';
        END IF;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Just run the function using:

```
SELECT * FROM check_tables_id();
```

The result you get is a list like this:

```
dbase=# select * from check_tables_id();
   tablename    
----------------
 dbase.table3
 dbase.table4
(2 rows)
```